# mapping data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I have a data stored in array

```
 $roles = [2,4];
```

I want to mapping the data I have in $roles with the data in the database. I don't know how to mapping data if I have more than one data in $roles like in above and I don't know how to show it all in a table view.

I try this

```
 if (count($roles) == 1) {
  if ($roles[0] == 2) {
    $data['need_app'] = $this->Hire_model->need_approval_req($OrganizationID, $requestor_id);
  }else if ($roles[0] == 3) {
    $data['need_app'] = $this->Hire_model->need_approval_recruiter();
  }else if ($roles[0] == 4) {
    $data['need_app']=$this->Hire_model->need_approval_hr();
  }else if ($roles[0] == 5) {
    $data['need_app'] = $this->Hire_model->need_approval_cc($PositionID, $OrganizationID, $requestor_id);
  }
}else{
   for ($i=0; $i < count($roles)-1 ; $i++) { 
    if ($roles[0] == 2) {
      $data['need_app'] = $this->Hire_model->need_approval_req($OrganizationID, $requestor_id);
      var_dump(count($data['need_app']));
    }else if ($roles[0] == 3) {
      $data['need_app'] = $this->Hire_model->need_approval_recruiter();
    }else if ($roles[0] == 4) {
      $data['need_app']=$this->Hire_model->need_approval_hr();
    }else if ($roles[0] == 5) {
      $data['need_app'] = $this->Hire_model->need_approval_cc($PositionID, $OrganizationID, $requestor_id);
      var_dump(count($data['need_app']));
    }
    // var_dump(count($data['need_app']));
  }
}
```

Hope anyone can help me

Comment: have you tried using `foreach`?

Comment: I already use it but it show the last foreach data

Comment: share the code where you're using `foreach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a code which should help you with this case, comments are mentioned wherever necessary. Hope it helps you.

```
foreach ($roles as $role) { 
    if ($role == 2) {
      $data['need_app'][] = $this->Hire_model->need_approval_req($OrganizationID, $requestor_id); // you need to make an array here otherwise the current value will over-write the previous one
      var_dump(count($data['need_app']));
    }else if ($role == 3) {
      $data['need_app'][] = $this->Hire_model->need_approval_recruiter(); // you need to make an array here otherwise the current value will over-write the previous one
    }else if ($role == 4) {
      $data['need_app'][] =$this->Hire_model->need_approval_hr(); // ...
    }else if ($role == 5) {
      $data['need_app'][] = $this->Hire_model->need_approval_cc($PositionID, $OrganizationID, $requestor_id); // ...
    }
    // var_dump($data['need_app']);
}
```

Comment: still can't to combine the data

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand what you're asking, please clarify.

Comment: when I am using it, it still show data for the last for each

Comment: The data will be saved as an array so you'll have to use `foreach` again to get the data.  In your `view` - `foreach($need_app as $need){ echo $need;}` This will give the value of each element in the array. You can then use it according to your needs.

Comment: I get it, but now, how to display it in a desc. I try foreach( $need_app as $row){} n get error.

Comment: If you want to show the data of an array in descending order you can use `rsort()` or `arsort()` before using `foreach`. See here - https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_sort.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach ($roles as $role) {

            if ($role == 2) {

                //your logic here

            } else if ($role == 4) {

                //your logic here

            } else if ($role == WHAT_EVER_YOU_WANTS) {
                //Logic
            }

            //your logic here
        }
```

SO based on your question

```
foreach ($roles as $role) {
            if ($role == 2) {
                $data['need_app'] = $this->Hire_model->need_approval_req($OrganizationID, $requestor_id);
            } else if ($role == 3) {
                $data['need_app'] = $this->Hire_model->need_approval_recruiter();
            } else if ($role == 4) {
                $data['need_app'] = $this->Hire_model->need_approval_hr();
            } else if ($role == 5) {
                $data['need_app'] = $this->Hire_model->need_approval_cc($PositionID, $OrganizationID, $requestor_id);
            }
        }
```

**Instead of using something like `$role == 4`**

Make a constant or another variable inside the function and loop the conditions with that variable values. This will be helpful for future modification.

Something like this

```
$loopValues = [1,2,3,4,5,6] // Or    $loopValues = [['val' => 1, 'function' => functionName()]] <- I prefer this one all the time
```

and then loop it like below

```
 foreach ($roles as $role) {

            if ($role == $loopValues[0]) {

                //your logic here
}
}
```

Comment: how to combine the data in one variable if I have 2,4 in $roles

Comment: You can use an array as I did  `$loopValues = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`